# jQuery not recognising click on modal close link ( href="#' )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ratchet-2, ratchet-bootstrap

I have modal close link which closes the open modal;

```
.clicker
   a.icon.icon-close.pull-left.closeover.white href="#mymodal"
```

and I have the following javascript on the page

```
$('.clicker').on( "click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('modal closed');
    });
```

I want to do something before (or directly after) closing the modal but the code doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

I'm using [ratchet](http://www.goratchet.com)

Answer (score 1):

The element is dynamically added in the dom, so event has to be delegated to the static parent:

```
$(document.body).on( "click", '.clicker', function(e) {
```

and this could be the issue:

[image]

Comment: that still doesn't work, I can't recognise any clicks within the modal

Comment: it recognises clicks in the modal but not on the actual link to close the modal, it always just closes and nothing gets triggered